# Pinterest like background color while image is loading

Tags: image-processing, web-scraping, pinterest

l am big fan of pinterest.
the feature that i like is the average background color displayed when the pin is loading.

I would like to know how to calculate the average color of image.

and second thing how to webscrape it.

thanks and regards.